# How can i calculate the opposite point if i have a point and a center?

Tags: objective-c, trigonometry, point

[image]

I have a center point and i know point 1, now i want to calculate point 2 which is in the opposite direction, but have another lenght. Also i know the lenght from the center point to point 2, but it is not on the same vector as Point 1 to center is. Imagine the dotted line has another angle as the image shows.

Point 2 should be on the same vector as is Point 1. In other words, Point 1 to Point 2 should be a straight line which pass trough the center.

I hope some one can help me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `Point2 = center + distance_from_center * normalized(center - Point1);`

Comment: Since this is a very math orientated question I need some clarification:
 Is this in a 2D plane, if so Cartesian or polar coordinates? If in a 3D space are you using vectors?

Comment: Its in 2D Plane.
Not sure what is polar coordinates

Comment: @MarcelloStanisci if you don't know what [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) are then you are using Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: This question makes more sense to be under math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there a particular computer language you want the answer in? Otherwise this would be a math question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

*Code assumes collinear points, in a 2D plane, defined as Cartesian coordinates*

In Java:

```
class GoGo {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    double[] center = new double[] { 4.0,3.0 };
    double[] point1 = new double[] { 8.0,4.0 };
    double[] point2 = getPoint2(center,point1,4.0);
    System.out.print("X: " + point2[0] + " Y: " +point2[1]);
  }
  public static double[] getPoint2(double[] center, double[] point1, double distance) {
    //assumes Points = double[2] { xValue, yValue }

    double[] point2   = new double[2];
    double changeInX  = point1[0] - center[0];   //  get delta x
    double changeInY  = point1[1] - center[1];   //  get delta y
    double distanceCto1 = Math.pow(              //   get distance Center to point1
                          (Math.pow(changeInX,2.0) + Math.pow(changeInY,2.0))
                          ,0.5);
    double distanceRatio = distance/distanceCto1;// ratio between distances
    double xValue = distanceRatio * changeInX;   // proportional change in x
    double yValue = distanceRatio * changeInY;   // proportional change in y
    point2[0] = center[0] - xValue;              // normalize from center
    point2[1] = center[0] - yValue;              // normalize from center
    return point2;                               // and return
  }
}
```

I wrote this in Java because it is *my* preferred language and you didn't specify a language you needed the answer in . If you have a different language preference, I can attempt to port the code to *your* preferred language (assuming I know it).

**CODE GIVEN BY: Marcello Stanisci**

In Objective C:

```
- (CGPoint) getOppositePointAtCenter2:(CGPoint)center fromPoint:(CGPoint)point oppositeDistance:(double)oppositeDistance {

    CGPoint vector = CGPointMake(point.x - center.x, point.y - center.y);
    double distanceCenterToPoint1 = pow(pow(vector.x, 2) + pow(vector.y, 2), 0.5);
    double distanceRatio = oppositeDistance / distanceCenterToPoint1;

    double xValue = distanceRatio * vector.x;
    double yValue = distanceRatio * vector.y;

    return CGPointMake(center.x - xValue, center.y - yValue);
}
```

Comment: I have made a mistake while converting your Java code to objective c.
Now i have corrected it and it works like a charm.
Thank you again very much.

Comment: @MarcelloStanisci I just edited the post, If you would like to re-edit the post with the corrected Objective C code, that would be useful for future viewers. Also maybe accept the answer...

Comment: I have corrected my code, maybe i have to wait a little bit just it is visible.
How can i now accept the answer ?